# What is the correct name for the node through which the internet “enters” a home network?

Tags: home-networking, isp

I hate asking this question because it seems like the answer should be obvious but I can't think of it.

I don't mean the box on the outside of the home. I mean the box in the home that usually connects to an RJ45 and then usually acts as the wireless access point for the home network.

I would call it a "router" because that's the word that's used in casual language but I don't think that's technically correct in this context because just calling it a router provides no indication that the internet is entering the home through it; there are routers that are not used as internet gateways.

So should the device be called an "internet gateway" or is that too general? Because not all internet gateways are devices used to connect homes to the internet. Perhaps "home internet gateaway"?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I feel like I should know the answer.

Comment: Maybe ["edge router"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-donley-dhc-cer-id-option-05) if just "router" is too ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

There is no sane answer for that anymore.

Today these boxes usually are hyperconverged appliances that bundle a modem, a router, a firewall, an ethernet switch, a wireless access point and maybe even a VoIP pbx system. So good luck coming up with a sane name for that.

If the device is owned by your ISPs it is usually called "CPE" for "Customer Premises Equipment" (at least by your ISP), because it is the equipment they care about on the Customer's Premises.

Most people call it a "router" today. I'd call it "gateway" (it has a default-route, so it is not really a router).

Comment: Having a default route doesn't disqualify a device from being a router. As long as it receives and forwards packets between interfaces according to IP-address-based routing table, it's a legitimate router... (In various company networks, even the "real", dedicated routers often have a partial table from BGP _plus_ a default route as a fallback. I think sometimes even full table + default route is used, though I'm not sure why)

Comment: Other than that... since OP specifically asked about a device that performs routing (and not e.g. just a modem/converter/ONT), I'd say this answer should work. "CPE" seems fairly ubiquitous.

Comment: @grawity BGP + default route is configured so you can login to the router from remote even if your routing daemons are down (i.e. neither BGP nor your link-state protocols work). Otherwise you'd have to jump from router to router because you can only connect to your next-hop. If you carefully planned your network and have a separated management-plane, you don't need the fallback default-route.
The term "CPE" is mostly used by ISPs (as I wrote) and yes, it doesn't apply to a specific class of device.

Comment: [That doesn't seem to be the only reason,](https://redd.it/9u37ry) according to people far more experienced than me.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the device that is responsible for connecting your home to the Internet is the `modem`. If you have more than one router, it would be appropriate to ask something like "where is your gateway?"

The purpose of the modem is the take the incoming carrier signals, and convert it to an Ethernet signal that your local devices understand. It also does the opposite conversion for the outbound data.

Many people use router/modem combos which helps connect you to the public Internet, and also takes care of your local network issues. The fact that most people only have one router/modem in their house, the term router seems to have become the most popular.

You can break down the responsibilities of each device like below, but these don't always apply 100%. It depends how the ISP has their infrastructure set up.

> Modem Responsibilities

- Connects your home to the Internet
- Has a public IP address
- Uses the WAN

> Router Responsibilities

- Helps connect your personal devices to the Internet
- Uses local IP addresses
- Uses a LAN network

Comment: This is plain wrong: The **modem** does not have a public IP address. The device **connected to the modem** (be it a router or a PC) has the public IP address

Comment: @EugenRieck I take exception to that comment. I understand the point you are trying to make but in the context of home internet “modems” the device needs to be managed by the ISP and that is usually done with its own public IP. In addition, being most ISP modems go beyond the pure “bridge” functionality that a modem actually is, they usually are also the next hop route even when the customer static IP is assigned to a device behind the modem. For these reasons they often do have their own public IP.

Comment: Your objection is plain wrong. While the box your provider sets up for you might do more than a modem does, the modem itself never ever has an IP address. Modem stands for **Modulator / Demodulator** which quite easily says what it does: It takes digital data (with no concept of a protocol and thus no IP address) and modulates it to an analog form to be physically transported over a link, additionally demodulating the received analog signal and extracting the digital payload.

Comment: @EugenRieck you’ve taken your concept to the extreme, but suit yourself. Using your description of a “modem” would be referring to a single integrated circuit on a larger circuit board, which by itself, without the command and control support circuitry would be useless. Therefore, ANY *functional* device would be outside the scope of your definition of “modem.” Whereas, in reality, any device called a modem, that actually plugs in to a computer or IP network, has a high likelihood of having an IP address.

Comment: @Appleoddity Again you are plain wrong. The modem I am writing this comment over does exactly what it is supposed to do, but not more. Making it possible to write a SE comment over it does IMHO qualify it as a *functional* device.

Comment: @EugenRieck please provide the make and model of “modem” you are using for the purpose of this discussion. Also indicate how it connects to your computer. Is it USB, Ethernet, rs-232, etc? Regardless, your modem does far more than you are willing to admit for some reason. It has to communicate with your computer, it has to receive and process commands, etc.

Comment: The modem is a TD-8614. It connects via Ethernet and the public IPs are configured on the router behind it, not on the modem. The modem has no configuration whatsoever, it just encodes the frames on the ethernet side and passes them through to the ISP and vice versa. Apart from this information I close this discussion: If you want to believe something else than the truth, you are welcome to ... I am not a missionary.